# IDLE will not launch/Tcl install error

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

As the title points out, IDLE will not launch in my Windows 7 system. I had Python 2.5.1 installed in my computer for a while. I recently installed Python 3.5 without getting rid of 2.5. After a few issues with the PATH variable, Python seems to be working fine. However, IDLE isn't.

When I try to launch idle from cmd i get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\idlelib>python idle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idle.py", line 11, in <module>
    idlelib.PyShell.main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1531, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1867, in __in
it__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:/Program Files/Python 3.5/lib/tcl8.6} {C:/Program Files/lib/tcl8.6} C:/li
b/tcl8.6 {C:/Program Files/library} C:/library C:/tcl8.6.4/library C:/tcl8.6.4/l
ibrary



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly."
```

While looking for a solution, I've seen this happens quite often (some posts date back to the early 2000's). Some people suggest to delete the TCL_LIBRARY environment variable, but there is no such variable in my system. Furthermore, when I do create the variable using

```
set TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\tcl\tcl8.6
```

Python does launch, but this solution is less than ideal since I would have to set the variable every time I open IDLE. I tried creating this variable directly in the system->Environment Variables... dialog, but it doesn't work that way.

Some other people have suggested to uninstall and re-install Tcl using python's modify option. I uninstalled the Tcl/tk option from the 2.5.1 and the 3.5, and then reinstalled it only for the 3.5. It didn't take care of the error.